# Don't understand this ImportError while running my script

Tags: python, import, blockchain

I'm running this code from [github](https://github.com/JungWinter/file-on-blockchain):

Everything works fine but in 3rd Step when I run:

```
cd file-on-blockchain/example
```

and in this when i execute this=> `python deploy_contract_and_test.py`, It says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deploy_contract_and_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
ImportError: No module named web3
```

I have seen many people's answers regarding updating `pip` and all, but nothings working.

Comment: `pip install --user web3`

Comment: @d_kennetz i've installed it but still its giving me the error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Try running `import web3` only and let know if there is an error

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal import web3 gave me this error => import-im6.q16: not authorized `web3' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.

Comment: Could you post the whole command that you used to import web3?

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal here i've uploaded a screenshot

Comment: https://ibb.co/j6xPcmz

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal what should i do now?

Comment: I think you need to get a good introductory course on python rather than just following the steps as a user guide you need to understand what's really going on and why to help learn faster and simpler

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal tell me the solution for this one please?

Comment: You need to run the codes in some python interpreter it depends on your installation on how to start it, in your case try typing `python` and hit enter it should show some ptthon interpreter

Comment: yes it is showing me the interpreter whats next?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have the `web3` module installed. You can install it using `pip`:

```
$ pip install web3
```

Answer (score 0):

there's more detailed information about how to install the package at the official github :

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py